# MySQL - UPDATE datetime

Tags: mysql, datetime, date, time

I'm trying to update a field based on other fields in a row and I need some help -- I keep getting unwanted results.

I have three fields

```
start_time DateTime
pause_time DateTime
end_time DateTime
```

What I'd like to do is move the end time forward by basically doing `end_time = (end_time + (NOW() - pause_time))`.

So, I'm figuring out how much time has elapsed since the pause time and NOW() then adding to the current end_time, thus moving it forward.

Should I be trying to look for unexpected behavior like pause_time being later than NOW() or anything like that? How could I do that? In a perfect situation, start time and pause time would be in the past and end_time in the future..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think this should work for you

`end_time=Date_ADD(end_time,Interval DATEDIFF(now(),pause_time) day)`

if not got to [MySql reference manual for date and time](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html)